# Unable to copy windows registry key to another PC

Tags: windows-registry, regedit, binary-files

I want to copy the registry key in the picture below to another PC but I've tried everything and I couldn't.

[image: Pic:]

How could I do this?

Comment: Did you try exporting and then importing?

Comment: @ignacico in binary files there is no option for exporting

Answer (score 6):

Terminology: The things in the left pane are called "keys", the right pane are called "values". (They're not files.) You can't export individual values, but you can export an entire key, then (if you want) edit the resulting .reg file to omit the values you don't want to copy.

Highlight the key you want to export, File | Export , you get a .reg file. Open it in Notepad - the structure will be obvious. Edit to tasted. Import it on your other machine or environment.

And good luck... registry contents aren't always usable on other machines without some tweaking.

Comment: Thank you but my problem is that when I export the reg file and move it to my other pc, after double clicking the reg file and confirming, I get an error message like this: "Cannot import D:\wnd.reg: Error accessing the registry."

Comment: Do it from an elevated command prompt (ie run as admin).